# Accessing Collection causes Subscript out of range error?

Tags: excel, vba, exception, runtime-error

I've got an `UserForm`, which upon an incorrect user input calls the following procedure, which highlights the field and disables the "save changes" button.

```
Private disabledElems As New Collection

Private Sub disable(ByRef controlName As String)
    UserForm1.Controls(controlName).BackColor = &H8080FF
    Me.save_button.Enabled = False
    Dim i As Byte

    If disabledElems.Count <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To disabledElems.Count
            If disabledElems(i) = controlName Then
                Exit Sub ' we dont want to add duplicates to collection
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    disabledElems.Add controlName ' otherwise add to collection

End Sub
```

If the input is corrected,  it calls the `enable` procedure, which looks like this:

```
Private Sub enable(ByRef controlName As String)
    Me.Controls(controlName).BackColor = &H80000005
    Dim i As Byte

    For i = 1 To disabledElems.Count
        If disabledElems(i) = controlName Then
            disabledElems.Remove i ' remove the enabled element upon match 
        End If
    Next i

    If disabledElems.Count = 0 Then
        save_button.Enabled = True
    End If


End Sub
```

> This seems to work just fine when I try this with one `Textbox`
>
> [image]

---

However, as soon I have **multiple incorrect entries**, my `enable` procedure seems to throw a **`Subscript out of range error`** seemingly for no reason.

The highlighted line in the debugger is:

```
If disabledElems(i) = controlName Then
```

[image]

*I can't comprehend what could be causing this. Any ideas?*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ah alright, it's one of those classical *"when removing a row, loop
>   from end to beginning"*

Basically, the reason why the **`Subscript out of range`** was thrown - once the element was removed from the collection via the

```
disabledElems.Remove i
```

It reduced the size of the `Collection` from `Collection.Count` to `Collection.Count - 1`, however during the `for` loop declaration, the `i` was already *hard-set* to the previous `Collection.Count`

---

> *In an practical example:*

Let's say my `Collection` looks like this

```
 disabledElems = "button1", "button2"
```

Upon doing this

```
controlName = "button1"
For i = 1 to disabledElems.Count ' <= 2
   If disabledElems(i) = controlName ' < True for i = 1
      disabledElems.Remove i ' < button1 was removed from collection, however it still loops
   End If
   ' will loop to i = 2. However disabledElems(2) no longer exists, because upon removal _
     the button2 was shifted to disabledElems(1) - hence Subscript out of range
Next i
```

A clear case of trying to access an element, which has shifted its position in the queue.

---

There are two possible fixes *(that I can think of)*:

**1. Enforce `Exit Sub` upon removal**

```
For i = 1 to disabledElems.Count
   If disabledElems(i) = controlName
       disabledElems.Remove i
       Exit Sub
   End If
Next i
```

**2. Loop from end to start**

```
Dim i as Integer ' needs to be redeclared to int, because Byte can't -1
For i = disabledElems.Count to 1 Step -1
   If disabledElems(i) = controlName
      disabledElems.Remove i
   End If
Next i
```